# Differences in array declaration

Tags: java, arrays

Recently I came across the types of array declaration in java like,

```
       int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
       int[] arr1 = new int[5];
       arr1[0] = 0;
       arr1[1] = 1; ..etc
```

Can anyone please explain what will be difference between these two things, like in memory allocation, access efficiency or any other?

Comment: Thanks to modern java compilers, there should not be any difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

They're equivalent (assuming you actually change the values in the first one to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.)

Indeed, they'll even compile to *nearly* the same bytecode; Java bytecode doesn't have anything cunning to make this simpler, so the compiler almost just expands the "inline" version to the "create and populate" version.

You can see this by compiling a short test app:

```
public class Test {
    private static void inline() {
        int[] x = { 0, 1, 2 };
    }

    private static void explicit() {
        int[] x = new int[3];
        x[0] = 0;
        x[1] = 1;
        x[2] = 2;
    }
}
```

And then using `javap` to show the bytecode:

```
$ javap -c --private Test

Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test extends java.lang.Object{
public Test();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

private static void inline();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_3
   1:   newarray int
   3:   dup
   4:   iconst_0
   5:   iconst_0
   6:   iastore
   7:   dup
   8:   iconst_1
   9:   iconst_1
   10:  iastore
   11:  dup
   12:  iconst_2
   13:  iconst_2
   14:  iastore
   15:  astore_0
   16:  return

private static void explicit();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_3
   1:   newarray int
   3:   astore_0
   4:   aload_0
   5:   iconst_0
   6:   iconst_0
   7:   iastore
   8:   aload_0
   9:   iconst_1
   10:  iconst_1
   11:  iastore
   12:  aload_0
   13:  iconst_2
   14:  iconst_2
   15:  iastore
   16:  return

}
```

(Compiled with the stock JDK 7. Of course exact compiler behaviour may vary.)

The only difference is that the "inline" version uses `dup` to access `x` each time, instead of using `aload_0`.

Memory usage will be the same, and I'd expect the JITted code to be identical (as it should be able to spot that `aload_0` and `dup` are doing the same thing here).

Comment: I don't doubt this, but a javap dump would be nice, here.

Comment: Very nice - I had already started the benchmarking route (which confirms that there is no difference) - but your observation settles the debate!

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent.

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

The value of the indexes is initialized with 1,2...5.

```
int[] arr1 = new int[5];
```

The value of the indexes is initialized with 0.Then you set the value of the index like below

arr1[0] = 0;
   arr1[1] = 1; ..etc

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Create an array and set the values.

```
int[] arr1 = new int[5];
arr1[0] = 0;
arr1[1] = 1;
```

The first line create an array that can contains 5 values but they are not set.
That is what the two last lines are doing.

About performance, it depends on read and write operation, in memory it is the same size

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in terms of efficiency or memory allocation.

Because this is an array of primitives the space is directy filled with the values, not just a reference. So if you declare an int array of 5 ints the memory for those ints is directly allocated then.

Filling it with values using `int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` is purely for the programmers convenience.

Answer (score 0):

No, there should not be any performance difference. Modern compilers should reduce both the cases to (almost) similar byte code.